# How to navigate to Specific Fragment in NavigationDrawer from an Activity

Tags: java, android

My problem is that I am using NavigationDrawer with multiple fragments. I have an Activity. I am trying to return from the activity to Specific Fragment. I have tried to send an intent. It works but it always stay in that fragment due to the bundle value is not null. So if you have a way how to make the bundle null or you have a better solution than the intent I will be grateful. Thanks, all.

This Method is capable of switching the Fragments

```
public void DisplaySelectedScreen(int id) {

        infoNom = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (infoNom != null) {
            id = Integer.valueOf(infoNom.getString("Fragment"));
        }

        infoNom = null ; //not Working

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragment = new Home();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_info:
                fragment = new Informations();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cmd:
                fragment = new Commandes();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_panier:
                fragment = new Cart();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_contact:
                fragment = new Contact();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_about_us:
                fragment = new About_Us();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                ParseUser.logOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Welcome.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    }
```

Comment: did you try this.getIntent().setExtras(null)?

Comment: there isn't setExtras() method !!

Comment: when you set bundle in intent did you pass any key like intent.putExtra("key",bundle)

Comment: of course i sent the id of the fragment !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the bundle using below method:

```
getIntent().removeExtra("key");
```

Hope It help you !

Answer (score 0):

Ways to replace extras

void removeExtra(String name)
Remove extended data from the intent.

void removeFlags(int flags)
Remove these flags from the intent.

Intent replaceExtras(Intent src)
Completely replace the extras in the Intent with the extras in the given Intent.

Intent replaceExtras(Bundle extras)
Completely replace the extras in the Intent with the given Bundle of extras.

Hope this helps